# Trying to understand the error

Tags: ruby

I was learning about the gem Rspec through a tutorial when this error came up.The last thing I typed in was

```
$ rspec spec spec\hello_world_spec.rb
```

I had only installed the Rspec gem and nothing else.

[the output message from the cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbThE.png)

Comment: Please post code, errors or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Try to get rid of `spec`

```
rspec spec\hello_world_spec.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `spec` and `spec\hello_world_spec.rb` as arguments to rspec. These are interpreted as files to run, or directories to search through for files to run. Since you're already running *in* the `spec\` directory, rspec is looking for `spec\spec\` and `spec\spec\hello_world_spec.rb`, which don't exist. Try running that from one directory up (in a typical ruby project, the "root" of your project) and it should run.

i.e. Instead of:

```
\rspec_tutorial\spec>rspec spec spec\hello_world_spec.rb
```

try:

```
\rspec_tutorial>rspec spec spec\hello_world_spec.rb
```

---

Also, as @Ursus points out, running `rspec spec spec\hello_world_spec.rb` is redundant. Rspec will search through spec\ for files to run and will run hello_world_spec.rb automatically since it's under spec. If you *only* want to run hello_world_spec.rb–which seems to be your intent–then drop the `spec` from the command, per @Ursus' answer.